# In Bash, how can I read the value of readline variable named `history-size`?

Tags: bash, command-history, readline

My Bash version I have updated from v590 to version 5.2.15(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu).

I use Kubuntu 20.04 and KNOPPIX 9.1.

The readline variable `history-size` can be set to on or off, can be bind to a key-sequece (but is normally unbound), and has a value.

The value is by default the value of `$HISTSIZE`.

I want to check the value of the variable `hist-size` in readline, if it is actually really equal to `$HISTSIZE` in the shell.

How can I read the value of the variable `hist-size`?

In earlier years I have used the "Readline Library", but now I cannot make use of it for this. Also in internet there is no article related to this.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash `bind` is an interface to talk to readline. `help bind` prints (among other lines):

> `-v`          List variable names and values in a form that can be reused as input.

This means you can use `bind -v`. The line you are interested in looks like this:

```
set history-size 50000
```

You can extract the value with `awk`:

```
bind -v | awk '/^set history-size / {print $3;}'
```

---

> I want to check the value of the variable `hist-size` in readline, if it is actually really equal to `$HISTSIZE` in the shell.

Example shell code:

```bash
readline_history_size="$(bind -v | awk '/^set history-size / {print $3;}')"
if [ "$readline_history_size" = "$HISTSIZE" ]; then
   echo yes
else
   echo no
fi
```

Note I deliberately used string comparison (`=`), not arithmetic comparison (`-eq`); this should reasonably work if one of the variables is unset. On the other hand a case of `$HISTSIZE` being `0100` and `$readline_history_size` being `100` begs for arithmetic comparison.

Additionally I note in my tests `HISTSIZE=-1` in the shell genuinely results in `history-size` being `0` in readline, so probably you should interpret certain discrepancies as sane anyway. You may want to build more complicated logic that covers all edge cases.

Comment: == 30.01.2023 14:00:: to answer of Kamil Macioroeski :: thanks for your very good answer. I have overlooked "bind -v". Thanks to you I have used it and got the result: value of history-size is 0.  To my horror. Yet very fine that you wrote, you got 0 due to "HISTZIZE -1", as I have set too. Thus value 0 is clarified. But it may caused my problems that led me to those investigations. -- I have to further deal with that. Regards